# ORA-01843: not a valid month error while loading data from csv to oracle db using python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

CSV date column is in following format 'MM/DD/YYYY' while loading the data into db Iam seeing following error:
Oracle-Error-Code: 1843
Oracle-Error-Message: ORA-01843: not a valid month

**Code:**

```
csv_input=pd.read_csv(r"C:\python\test.csv",index_col=False,na_values=" ").fillna('')


try:
    conn = orcCon.connect('scott/tiger@localhost:1521/orcl',encoding="UTF-8")
    if conn:
        print("cx_Oracle version:", orcCon.version)
        print("Database version:", conn.version)
        print("Client version:", orcCon.clientversion())
        
        # Now execute the sqlquery 
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("You're connected.................")
        print("TRUNCATING THE TARGET TABLE")
        cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TEST1")
        print("Inserting data into table")
        for i,row in csv_input.iterrows():
            sql = "INSERT INTO TEST1(SAMPLE1,SAMPLE2)VALUES(TO_DATE(:1,'MM/DD/YYYY'),:2)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            # the connection is not autocommitted by default, so we must commit to save our changes
            conn.commit()
            #print("Record inserted successfullly")
except DatabaseError as e:
    err, = e.args
    print("Oracle-Error-Code:", err.code)
    print("Oracle-Error-Message:", err.message)

finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

CSV is in following format:

```
Sample1          Sample2
11/23/2022       abc
11/23/2022       bcd
```

Comment: super dumb questions, apologies in advance, it's not trying to read 'Sample1' as a date, is it? make sure it's starting on line 2. Also, issuing a COMMIT for every single record won't be fast, how big is your CSV file?

Comment: Do some debugging on the data and see if just some values are 'bad'.  You can improve performance by using `executemany()` as shown [in the documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database) for loading CSVs.  (The same applies to the old cx_Oracle release).  One great this about `executemany()` is the `batchErrors` setting see [here](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#handling-data-errors) which can help skip invalid data.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I have mentioned index_col=False while reading the csv file which reads csv file from line 2

Comment: @ChristopherJones When i change the format in csv file to DD-MON-YYYY it is loading without issue

Answer (score 1):

You have only one problem, but is is *serious*. You use `read_csv` but your input data is **not** a `csv` file.

```
t="""Sample1          Sample2
11/23/2022       abc
11/23/2022       bcd"""
csv_input = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
for i,row in csv_input.iterrows():
    print(f'reading: {tuple(row)}')

reading: ('11/23/2022       abc',)
reading: ('11/23/2022       bcd',)
```

So you are reading a *tuple* with **one** value which leads to the conversion problem.

You have to use `read_fwf` - for fixed width files

```
fwf_input = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t))
for i,row in fwf_input.iterrows():
    print(f'reading: {tuple(row)}') 

reading: ('11/23/2022', 'abc')
reading: ('11/23/2022', 'bcd')
```